# How do I solve this problem ? I'm trying to build an android app based on Kotlin, but I keep getting this error

Tags: android-studio

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Ussumane-Momade\Documents\HappyBirthday\app\build\intermediates\manifest_merge_blame_file\debug\manifest-merger-blame-debug-report.txt (Access is denied)

Comment: try invalidate cache and restart in android studio, It will fix the issue probably

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've changed the Project to another folder and it's working Just fine
Thanks